# Mongodb update command ask

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

What is the command that can update data shown in image1 to become data shown in image2,

I use `update $push`, but doesn't work.

Error for the command is:

> Cannot apply $push modifier to non-array for field 'single'

Starts as:

[image]

I want it to be:

[image]

Comment: Please show your update code and the exact structure of the object you are trying to update.

Comment: sorry, this is my first ask question, i had try, but fail, next time i will forces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents should be selected by some field. `_id` field is the most common for selection. I've used `_id` from your screenshot.

```
const _id = 'z6cQHB4WauGgCBGxM';
db.collection.update({
  _id: _id
}, {
  $push: {
    'single.hub': {
      context: 222
    }
  }
});
```